# how to get a result in text format using command in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

how to get a result in text format using command in sql server?. I know we can get it using ctrl+T, but I need to know if any sql command is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably thinking about magic comments, something like `!set output plain_text`. In that case, the answer is no, SSMS does not have it.

You can display the query result in plain text by selecting **Query > Results to > Results to Text**. Shortcut: `Ctrl + T`